# AWS SDK .NET custom metadata with non-ASCII characters

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload object to S3 with custom metadata. If I use ASCII only it works fine (I use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to escape some special symbols).

However if I want to send a text with French symbols in it I got S3 exception (same as if I used unescaped special symbols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use non-ASCII characters for S3 user-defined metadata when using either REST API or the AWS SDK (since AWS SDK is basically wrapper libraries that wrap the underlying Amazon S3 REST API):

> User-defined metadata is a set of key-value pairs. Amazon S3 stores
>   user-defined metadata keys in lowercase. Each key-value pair must
>   conform to **US-ASCII when you are using REST** and to UTF-8 when you are
>   using SOAP or browser-based uploads via POST.

While UTF-8 is supported for both; SOAP and browser-based uploads using POST, AWS [recommends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APISoap.html) that you use either the REST API or the AWS SDKs saying that new features will not be supported for SOAP:

> SOAP support over HTTP is deprecated, but it is still available over
>   HTTPS. New Amazon S3 features will not be supported for SOAP. We
>   recommend that you use either the REST API or the AWS SDKs.

Comment: I saw that doc but wasn't sure if aws uses rest or not.. thanks.